# Detect when user select text in richTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm making a form with tabcontrol. When user open a new tab, the program will create new rtb like this:

```
RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
TabPage tb = new TabPage();
tb.Text = textBox1.Text;
tabControl.TabPages.Add(tb);
rtb.Parent = tb;
rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

This is how can I access the richTextBox of current selected tabpage:

```
RichTextBox rtb = tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0] as RichTextBox;
```

I'm wondering how can I get the **SelectionChanged** event of this rtb?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: @AsthaSrivastava what is the problem with the question?

Comment: You have to assign the `SelectionChanged` event when you create that control, which means you need to write an event handler first. You can tell which control fired the event using the `Sender` parameter.

Comment: @KenWhite Is this right? private void rtb_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Ken-White's comment, you need to attach onto the SelectionChanged event

```
{
     rtb.SelectionChanged += SelectionChangedEventHandler;
}

void SelectionChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs ev)
{
    RichTextBox rb = sender as RichTextBox;
    Console.WriteLine(rb.SelectedText);
}
```

Comment: Where can I put the **rtb.SelectionChanged += SelectionChangedEventHandler;**?

Answer (score 0):

Ryan's answer is correct.  But you can do this with the designer as well.

- Select your RichTextBox
- Bring up Properties (F4 is the default)
- Click the [Events] button (green in image below)
- Double-click "SelectionChanged"  (red in image below)

[image]